# Cannot create service Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, service, xamarin.android

Im trying to create a media player service in xamarin but whenever i call Startservice like this

```
StartService(new Intent(ApplicationContext,typeof(StreamingBackgroundService)));
```

the onCreate method is never called. I have added the service to the androidmanifest.xml
like this

```
<application android:label="PlayYoutubeMP3" android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
```

But it doesnt do anything either. I am using Android api 23 and visual studio 2017. I honestly have no idea what i am doing wrong. any help would be appreciated

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Media;

    [Service(Label = "StreamingBackgroundService", Icon = "@drawable/Icon")]
    public class StreamingBackgroundService : Service, SendCommand
    {
        private MediaPlayer player;


        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }


        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            MainActivity.Event = this;
            base.OnCreate();
        }
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            //Set sticky as we are a long running operation
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public void Play()
        {
            player.Start();
        }

        private void Pause()
        {
            player.Pause();
        }

        private void Stop()
        {
            player.Stop();
        }

        public void SendCommand(Command C, object Param = null)
        {
            switch (C)
            {
                case Command.Start:
                    Play();
                    break;
                case Command.Stop:
                    Stop();
                    break;
                case Command.Pause:
                    Pause();
                    break;
                case Command.Reset:
                    player.Reset();
                    break;
                case Command.GoBack:

                    break;
                case Command.GoForward:

                    break;
                case Command.Initialize:
                    player.SetDataSource((string)Param);
                    player.Prepare();
                    player.SetWakeMode(ApplicationContext, WakeLockFlags.Partial);
                    break;
                case Command.ShouldLoop:
                    player.Looping = (bool)Param;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Nothing happens`... what are you expecting to happen? Place a breakpoint in the OnCreate() method to confirm that your StartService call is actually creating the service. Also using a static Activity reference to be able to call methods within the service is in general a bad idea, you should use a bound service in order to access a service methods

Comment: I did its never called

Comment: The `[Service]` attribute handles updating the manifest during the build process so you should not manually update the manifest as it will be using an md5 name by default.

Comment: I have tried that. oncreate is still never called

Comment: i only added it to the manifest after it didnt work.

Comment: I test your code and it works fine by my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to a bound service, like SushiHangover suggested. That worked